# In magento 2, zip code text box to search the store available or not

Tags: api, magento, module, magento2

I am new to Magento.

I want a text box where i can type the zip code and if the store available in that location then i need to show the products of that particular store otherwise we need to show that "the store is not available in particular location".

The following is the example site. i want it as it is.
this site prompts for users zip location .after it will display stores of that particular.

[Click on this link to see the working example](http://burpy.com/)

how do i do this . Do i need to install a module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow Some Steps:**

> You need an entity 'store' that is bound to a geo location.
>
> You need to create a multi select attribute which values are located (using a 
>     source model) with these stores. This way, you can attach a single product to 
>     multiple stores (one to many relation)
>
> Then you need some sort of external API to convert a postcode entered by the 
>     customer to a geo location. I assume the Google Maps API can do this. It would 
>     be best to handle this server side.
>
> Then you need the math to calculate the distance between 2 geo locations in 
>     your database query (probably enough to find on that subject on Google) and 
>     filter your product collection on that.
>
> Once you have the collection you have the power.
>
> The external API will probably have a request threshold so you might have to 
>     pay for that (depending on the traffic).
>
> You need to determine the radius of maximum distance between 2 geo locations. 
>     In a small country like the Netherlands stores could be a couple of km's apart 
>     from each other, whilst in the United States it's not uncommon to have stores 
>     tens or hundreds of km's from each other.

```
                     **Best Of Luck For Your Project**
```